# Remove class before clicking on another table row HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below code retrieves the table html element and contains an onclick function. On this it calls a bunch of functions which works completely fine. The last part of the function is to highlight the table row using the class .primary. There should only ever be one row highlighted with this class. How do I change the function so that it removes the class before you click on another row. At the moment if you click on a row it highlights the entire row yellow. But when you click on another row it also highlights thats one yellow. I just want one row to be highlighted each time:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("tabledt");
if (table) {
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
      if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
        highlightMarker(prevHighlightMarker, false);
        tableText(this);
        highlightMarker(cMarkers[$(this).data('id')], true);
        this.classList.add("primary");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```css
.primary {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: When you receive a click, remove the primary class from the element that has it, unless the element with the class was the clicked one. You should have none or one rows highlighted, not 2.

Comment: How do i remove the primary class from the element that has it? The click function happens on table.rows[i].onclick so I have lost the previous row that has the CSS applied to it?

Comment: `var prevSelectedItem = document.querySelector('tr.primary');` followed by `prevSelectedItem.classList.remove('primary');`

Comment: What was the point of having `var prevHighlightMarker = undefined;`, if you never _set_ that to the current element anywhere? (If you properly did that, then you would have the reference to the _previous_ element in that the next time.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using jquery. There is a function in jquery that is useful in this cases.

```
siblings()
```

siblings selects all the all the elements with same parent. and you can filter it as you wish. https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

In this case you can do this way:

```
$("#tabledt tr").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('tr').removeClass('primary');
}
```